# Jetty Security Configuration Error

Tags: security, jetty

I have jetty 8.1.10 and want to secure it. This is from jetty.xml:

```
<Call name="addBean">
  <Arg>
    <New id="DeploymentManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager">
      <Set name="contexts">
        <Ref id="Contexts" />
      </Set>
      <Call name="setContextAttribute">            
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
        <Arg>.*/servlet-api-[^/]*\.jar$</Arg>
      </Call>                      
    </New>
  </Arg>
 </Call>


<Call name="addBean">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
      <Set name="name">Test Realm2</Set>
      <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/home/user/Desktop/solr-4.10.2/example/etc/realm.properties</Set>
      <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

This is from web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
  <role-name>solr</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
 <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
 <realm-name>Test Realm2</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

This is my realm.properties:

```
guest: guest, solr
```

When I want to login application it prompts for credentials. However even I enter guest and guest as username and password it infinitely re-prompts for credentials.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your realm.properties file?

Comment: @JasperSiepkes I've indicated it at my question: `guest: guest, solr`